# How to search in Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)

Tags: support, data-explorer

In Data Explorer, I would like to SELECT the same posts that would show up if I'd run a search on Stack Overflow.

For example, when I run [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=if%20loop) on Stack Overflow, it currently shows 604,031 results. These posts I would like to analyze in Data Explorer.

What condition do I have to put in?

(Actually I was trying to find out whether "postgresql explain" is more on topic on Stack Overflow or *[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour)*, by comparing their accept rates.)

Comment: You can't do it in a simple way, or in any way that would be accurate. SEDE and the per-site search mechanism are two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will break the Data Explorer with [that query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/522926):

```sql
select  id as [Post Link]
from posts
where body like '%if%'
or body like '%loop%'
```

This will end in an error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Because there are no full text search indexes present in the [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) instance SEDE is running on. The query has to do a full scan of all rows in the `Posts` table. Beyond that, SEDE will [never return more that 50.000 rows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234774/158100). SEDE is also only refreshed weekly.

If you limit the scope to a specific tag, for example [progresql](/questions/tagged/progresql) and gather some stats you can get some [results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/522928):

```
select sum(case
       when acceptedanswerid is not null
       then 1
       else 0 end) as [accepted]
       , count(*) as [all]
from posts  p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = 'postgresql'
and p.body like '%explain%'
```

By switching the site you can run this on other databases and compare their outcome.

Comment: I was trying to find out whether "postgresql explain" is more on topic on SO or dba, by comparing their accept rates.

Comment: @AndreKR that might be answered with the query I just added