# How to obtain the users reputation dataset from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, reputation, data-analysis

Is it possible to obtain the individual user reputations dataset (users and reputation at a given time) from Stack Overflow for example? Aim: modeling purposes.

Comment: If you want to look at all users, you'll need to download [the Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (45GB of XML), or perform your query on [the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (a tool for running SQL queries against the data set online, though with a timeout that may be prohibitive depending on what you want to do). [The API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) also allows you to gather information about users (also subject to rate limits).

Comment: Can you clarify "dataset"? Do you just mean a list of users and their reputation? Or do you mean the full details as in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation)? The former can be obtained through SEDE or the API like Jeremy mentioned. The latter is not available to us common folk, you can reconstruct *some* of the info from SEDE but not all. If you're looking for rep changes over time for a specific user I suppose you could scrape http://stackexchange.com/users/USER_ID?tab=reputation

Comment: I mean the info containing just the users and the reputation at a given time.

Comment: @JasonC The data SE gives back at most 50000 rows for a query.

Comment: @user54652 Then all of the methods Jeremy listed will work. Note that there are 6892675 users on SO, but SEDE queries are limited to 50000 results, so you'd want to either use [`OFFSET`/`FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) to page the results (tedious) or come up with some limiting criteria to keep the result set small. You might even be able to do a lot of the work of your analysis itself in a query. For the API it's easier to automate, subject to rate and quota limits. For the downloadable dumps you can do whatever, you'll have to parse XML.

Comment: @peterh Yes that is correct. You can still use SEDE to get it all. Just not in one shot.

Comment: @JasonC Right :-)

Comment: you can't get reputation at a given time, only current rep from a single datasource (be it SEDE or the datadump) so you have to get all datadumps and then buildup the timeseries from that. If you only need a few columns from a table but want to fetch more then 50,000 rows have a look at this [trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234774/158100)

Comment: I think that 25k reputation is required to access that sort of data.

Comment: @John [The 25k "site analytics" privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) you're referring to contains some aggregate statistics that are not available anywhere else, but doesn't provide any large data sets like are being requested here.

Comment: I forgot the other option for querying the data without downloading it: [the Data Dump data set is also available in Google BigQuery public datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow). However, this requires a Google Cloud account and may const money if you're not in the free tier.