# How to get refined data of a Stack Exchange website

Tags: support, data-explorer

I have used the following SQL query on Academia Stack Exchange:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts
```

This query generated 50,000 rows ... but the total number of questions on the website is approximately 28,000.

With that, it retrieves many missing values: the body of the post is present, but title and tags are missing for some of them.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Posts` table contains both questions and answers (and some other types as well, e.g. tag wikis and excerpts). The total number of posts on Academia is (as of last Sunday morning) [95,073](https://data.stackexchange.com/academia/query/1053760) but the maximum number of rows returned by SEDE is [50,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213050/why-cant-i-pull-in-all-the-so-users-from-data-explorer#comment685853_213050), so that's why you only get 50,000 rows.

The title and tags will only be present for questions, not for the other types of posts. They simply don't have those properties.

Most information you'll need will be in the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677), and you'll probably be interested in the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response...i want to download the data of all question posts which have title , tag, creationDate, body of the posts...how to get that only

Comment: SELECT Title, Tags, Body
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1

Comment: That should work, yes.